# Set cookie in Observer Not working when full page Cache is enabled

Tags: category, event-observer, magento2.3, cookie

I have to set category id in cookie when customer go to Category page and update cookie with category id when visit again using seperate module.

I have created Observer and set cookie there but not working. I have checked Observer is calling and also getting correct category ID.

Issue is with Cache. if Cache is enabled all is working fine.

> events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">

<event name="catalog_controller_category_init_after">

    <observer name="cookieObserver" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\Category\Data" />

</event>

</config>
```

> Observer - Data.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer\Category;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\CookieMetadataFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\CookieManagerInterface;


class Data implements ObserverInterface
{

const COOKIE_NAME = 'categoryId';
const COOKIE_DURATION = 86400; // One day (86400 seconds)

protected $cookieManager;

/**
 * @var CookieMetadataFactory
 */
protected $cookieMetadataFactory;

public function __construct(
    CookieManagerInterface $cookieManager,
    CookieMetadataFactory $cookieMetadataFactory
)
{
    $this->cookieManager = $cookieManager;
    $this->cookieMetadataFactory = $cookieMetadataFactory;
}

/**

 * Below is the method that will fire whenever the event runs!

 *

 * @param Observer $observer

 */

public function execute(Observer $observer)
{
    $data = $observer->getData();
    $metadata = $this->cookieMetadataFactory->createPublicCookieMetadata()->setDuration(86400)->setPath('/');
    $this->cookieManager->setPublicCookie('categoryId', $data['category']->getId(), $metadata);
```

return $this; 
    }

```
}
```

Please provide some suggestion or help.

Comment: Did you found solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `event`, `observer` to create/update/delete cookie when some visiting category page.

You can use the event `catalog_controller_category_init_after` or any other event like `layout_load_before`.

```
/* Set cookie */

$categoryId       = 'Category ID'
$objectManager    = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$cookieManager    = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Framework\Stdlib\CookieManagerInterface');
$cookieMetadataFactory = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\CookieMetadataFactory');
$metadata         = $cookieMetadataFactory
                    ->createPublicCookieMetadata()
                    ->setDuration(1800)
                    ->setPath('/');
$cookieManager->setPublicCookie(
    'categoryId',
    $categoryId,
    $metadata
);


/* Retrive the cookie values */

$cookieManager    = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Framework\Stdlib\CookieManagerInterface');
$cookieValue      = $cookieManager->getCookie('categoryId');
```

You can follow [manual](https://devdocs.magento.com/videos/fundamentals/create-a-new-module/) to create a custom extension

Comment: I have updated question.

Comment: @Magecode i have posted the working code, go through your code and debug it.

Comment: @Magecode make sure $data['category']->getId() providing the id or you can pass the static vale for now and check in your browser

Comment: I have passed static to.

Comment: post the browser screenshot which shows cookies

Comment: https://www.screencast.com/t/dHbMwu197qO

Comment: I have passed your code in Observer to but your code also not working in Observer

Comment: @Magecode you are doing something wrong

Comment: Please Tell me what is wrong there

Comment: Share your events.xml

Comment: Added in question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92190/discussion-between-magecode-and-rakesh-jakhar).

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/347741/magento-2-4-cookie-not-setting-via-observer-code